# When in localhost AdminBro bundle function is taking path, but when deployed to the Vercel production getting error, why?

Tags: express, vercel, admin-bro

> In the local server, it is working correctly. Only when deployed to Vercel getting this error.

> This is the following code - (The error is occurring in the AdminBro.bundle as it is not taking the argument.)

```
imagePath: {
            isVisible: { list: false, filter: false, show: true, edit: true },
            components: {
              show: AdminBro.bundle(
                "components/admin-imgPath-component.jsx"
              ),
            },
          },
```

> The error I am getting.

```
2021-08-26T18:14:08.075Z    undefined   ERROR   ConfigurationError: 
    Given file "components/admin-imgPath-component.jsx", doesn't exist.
    More information can be found at: https://softwarebrothers.github.io/admin-bro-dev/AdminBro.html
    at Function.bundle (/var/task/node_modules/admin-bro/lib/admin-bro.js:375:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/routes/admin.js:47:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/app.js:25:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
RequestId: ce1bf09a-857f-4c40-8a3b-e8a1762590bb Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: do you find any sulotion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
show: AdminBro.bundle(
            "components/admin-imgPath-component"
          ),
```

WITHOUT extension at the end.
Make sure that adminjs automatically generates an folder with file `.adminjs/.entry.js` where the Component gets linked to the AdminJS instance.